# Почему разница в вычислениях/кастинге между (long)z и (long)(x+y)?

Tags: c#, .net

Тестирую на .NET Framework 4.5.2 x86

```
float test1 = 1.3F,
      test2 = 5.2F;
float i2_float = test1 * 100,
      i3_float = test2 * 100;
long i1 = (long)i2_float;
long i2 = (long)i3_float;
```

Для первого варианта получаю следующие значения: i1=130, i2=520

```
float test1 = 1.3F,
      test2 = 5.2F;
long i1 = (long)(test1 * 100);
long i2 = (long)(test2 * 100);
```

Для второго получаю следующие значения: i1=129, i2=519

Почему получаю разные результаты для i1/i2 если результат операций test * 100 в обеих вариантах равен float и явно кастится в long?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. 
**Добавьте в вопрос, "какую" именно разницу вы получаете.**

Comment: Скомпилировал оба ваши примера, получаю в обоих случаях 130 и 520, что вполне является ожидаемым результатом. Перепроверьте данные. А, стоп, на .NET 6 проверяли? Возможно это баг из 4.5.2

Comment: @aepot, Вы проверили на .NET Framework 4.5.2 x86?

Comment: Проверил, воспроизвелось даже на более новом 4.x, это баг .NET Framework, очевидно. Потому что на .NET 6 все работает как и должно.

Comment: @aepot, проверял на .NET 3.1 и .NET 6. Неважно х64/x86 - результат правильный. Только с х86 фреймворком проблема

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8911646/12888024 здесь объяснение.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо)

Comment: Если вкратце, то, видимо, в процессе вычисления `test1 * 100` имеет точность большую, чем `float`. Поэтому если сразу привести в `long`, то результат получается более точный. А если сначала сложить результат этого вычисления опять в `float`, то он там как-то обрежется/округлится и последующий `long` будет преобразовывать уже другое число.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы понять, надо вспомнить, что `float` - это число с плавающей точкой, а следовательно все операции, производимые с ним, могут иметь погрешность в рамках его уровня точности.

Наверняка воспроизводимый код у меня не получилось сделать, чтобы показать, что там внутри, но по факту, там что-то типа `1.29999999998` вместо `1.3`, которое вы умножаете на `100`, затем приведением к `long` отбрасываете дробную часть, и получается `129`. То же самое для второго числа.

Почему `float i2_float = test1 * 100` работает: потому что компилятор умный и он решил оптимизировать ваше умножение как работу с константами, то есть ваш код скомпилируется во что-то типа `long i1 = 130L;` и никаких упоминаний в скомпилированном коде о `float` не будет. То есть финальное значение до какой-то степени будет вычислено на этапе компиляции. Точно так же как если бы у вас было `const float test1 = 1.3F`.

Почему разница результата в двух примерах: компилятор в .NET 4.x недостаточно умный, чтобы оптимизировать оба примера, у него хватило алгоритмов только на 1 из двух, а вот компилятор в .NET 6 - уже умнее и смог распознать и оптимизировать оба случая.

Comment: спасибо большое)